# How to add scanner in this program? If a user wants to input the value

Tags: java, string, split, reverse, charat

```
public class ReverseString {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String reverse = "";
        String obj = new String("BOOKS");
        for ( int i = obj.length() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
            reverse = reverse + obj.charAt(i);
        System.err.println("Orignal string is: "+obj);
        System.out.println("Reverse string is: "+reverse);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); String obj = scan.nextLine();`

Comment: Welcome on SO, please see [ask], you should have tried to search about `Scanner` and java to find more than enough examples online. Even the [`Scanner javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)  provides examples. This lack of effort from you is the reason you get down-voted by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Import scanner, then create its object and use it to take user input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//Statements of your code
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String obj = sc.nextLine();
//Statements of your code
}
```

Comment: how to read input from a file then write again on a file?

Comment: write again on same file?